# Hosts File for Greenplum Installation

Tags: greenplum

I am setting up greenplum 3 node cluster for POC while checking installation steps I found that hostfile_exkeys file have to be in master node.
Can anyone tell me where I should create this file location, node etc?
And most important what to put in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create hostfile_exkeys on the Master.  It isn't needed on the other hosts.  You can put it in /home/gpadmin or anywhere that is convenient for you.

You put the three hostnames for your POC in this file.  Example:

```
mdw
sdw1
sdw2
```

This is documented pretty well here: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5120/install_guide/prep_os_install_gpdb.html

You can also run a POC in the cloud.  Greenplum is available in AWS, Azure, and GCP.  It does all of the configuration for you.  You can even use the BYOL product listings for 90 days for free to evaluate the product or you can use the Hourly billed products to get support while you evaluate the product.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the utililty reference for gpssh-exkeys documentation but, in general, you should put in all the hostnames in your cluster.  If there a multiple network-interfaces, those can go in instead.

I generally put this file either in /home/gpadmin or /home/gpadmin/gpconfigs (good place to keep all files for initial setup and initialization).

Your file will look something like (one name per line):

mdw
sdw1
sdw2

If there are 2 network interfaces, it might look something like:

mdw
mdw-1
mdw-2
sdw1
sdw1-1
sdw1-2
sdw2
sdw2-1
sdw2-2

Your /etc/hosts file (on all server) should include the IP addresses for all the interfaces and their names, so this file should match those names listed in /etc/hosts.

This is primarily to allow the master to exchange ssh keys with all hosts so it is always password-less login to the hosts.   After you have this file set up, you will run (example):

gpssh-exkeys -f /home/gpadmin/gpconfigs/yourhostfilename

I hope this helps.

Comment: The formatting of the hostfile-exkeys file is one host/interface name per line.   I had it formatted like that but it didn't show up.   Don't put everything on one line as it appears here.,